# Using divs to keep headers in place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a filter search list which splits in three categories:

- Comunicados
- Training On the Job
- Documentos

The filter works great while looking for any of the terms nested under these categories but there's an annoying movement of the headers when this operation is performed.

For example, anytime you enter the phrase "Cuenta NT" the other two headers move down.

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('myInput');
var drinks = document.querySelectorAll('.des');

filter.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var s = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  drinks.forEach(function(el, i) {
    if (s.length > 3) {
      if (el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) < 0) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        el.style.display = 'block';
      }
    } else {
      drinks.forEach(function(el, i) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

#myInput {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.list {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.list li:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#list1 {
  width: 25%;
}

#h1 {
  background: #e65c00;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F9D423, #e65c00);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F9D423, #e65c00);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: initial;
}

#list1 a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#list1 li a:hover {
  background-color: #FCF3CF;
}

#list2 {
  width: 25%;
}

#h2 {
  background: #00b09b;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #96c93d, #00b09b);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #96c93d, #00b09b);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#list2 a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#list2 li a:hover {
  background-color: #b8ede2;
}

#list3 {
  width: 25%;
}

#h3 {
  background: #36D1DC;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #5B86E5, #36D1DC);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #5B86E5, #36D1DC);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#list3 a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#list3 li a:hover {
  background-color: #D6EAF8;
}

p.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0.1px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      </br>
      <div class="center">
         <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar">
      </div>
      </br>
      </br>
      <div class="center">
         <ul id="list1" class="list">
            <li id="h1">COMUNICADOS</li>
            <li class="des">
               <a target="_blank" href="#">
                  Cuenta NT
                  <p class="invisible">
                     Cuenta de red
                  </p>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="des">Document2</li>
            <li class="des">Document3</li>
         </ul>
         <ul id="list2" class="list">
            <li id="h2">TRAINING ON THE JOB</li>
            <li class="des">
               <a target="_blank" href="#">
                  Training On the Job
                  <p class="invisible">
                     Training On the Job
                  </p>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="des">Document2</li>
            <li class="des">Document3</li>
         </ul>
         <ul id="list3" class="list">
            <li id="h3">DOCUMENTOS</li>
            <li class="des">
               <a target="_blank" href="#">
                  Procedimiento Atención Usuario VIP
                  <p class="invisible">
                     VIP
                  </p>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="des">Document2</li>
            <li class="des">Document3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `align-items:center;` from `.center` class and add `margin-top:20px //or whatever value you want` to the `.list` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/64f50c97/1/

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `<ul>` and `<li>`, the way to go is to add

```
display: table-column;
margin-top: 20px;
```

to  `.list` and `display: table;` to `.center`.

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('myInput');
var drinks = document.querySelectorAll('.des');

filter.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
  var s = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  drinks.forEach(function(el,i){
    if(s.length > 3){
       if(el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) < 0){
        el.style.display = 'none';
       }else{
        el.style.display = 'block';
       }
     }else{
       drinks.forEach(function(el,i){
        el.style.display = 'block';
       });
     }
     
  });
});
```

```css
.center {
    align-items: center;
    border: 3px solid hsl(85, 68%, 40%);
    display: table;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
.container {
    border: 3px solid hsl(85, 68%, 40%);
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#myInput {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 60%;
}
.list {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 96%);
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    display: table-column;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.list li:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#list1 {
    width: 25%;
}
#h1 {
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) linear-gradient(to right, hsl(50, 95%, 56%), hsl(24, 100%, 45%)) repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    position: initial;
    text-align: center;
}
#list1 a {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 96%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#list1 li a:hover {
    background-color: hsl(48, 88%, 90%);
}
#list2 {
    width: 25%;
}
#h2 {
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) linear-gradient(to right, hsl(82, 56%, 51%), hsl(173, 100%, 35%)) repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#list2 a {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 96%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#list2 li a:hover {
    background-color: hsl(168, 60%, 83%);
}
#list3 {
    width: 25%;
}
#h3 {
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) linear-gradient(to left, hsl(221, 73%, 63%), hsl(184, 70%, 54%)) repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#list3 a {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 96%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#list3 li a:hover {
    background-color: hsl(205, 71%, 91%);
}
p.invisible {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 0.1px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
  
<body>

</br>
<div class="center">
 <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar">
</div>
 </br>
</br>

<div class="center">
<ul id="list1" class="list">
  <li id="h1">COMUNICADOS</li>

  <li class="des"><a target="_blank" href="#">Cuenta NT
   <p class="invisible">
   Cuenta de red
   </p></a></li>  
  <li class="des">Document2</li>
  <li class="des">Document3</li>
</ul>



<ul id="list2" class="list">
  <li id="h2">TRAINING ON THE JOB</li>

  <li class="des"><a target="_blank" href="#">Training On the Job
   <p class="invisible">
   Training On the Job
   </p></a></li>  
  <li class="des">Document2</li>
  <li class="des">Document3</li>
</ul>



<ul id="list3" class="list">
  <li id="h3">DOCUMENTOS</li>

  <li class="des"><a target="_blank" href="#">Procedimiento Atención Usuario VIP
   <p class="invisible">
   VIP
   </p></a></li>  
  <li class="des">Document2</li>
  <li class="des">Document3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```